# react navigation define drawer navigation with custom components using redux

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

I am creating a React Native app wherein I have a `SwitchNavigator` which takes me either to a `LoginStack` or a `Drawer` (depending on the loginState, post-login also the user reaches the Drawer).

**After Logging the user in**, I have a requirement wherein depending on the user's details fetched through a login (account etc), I **fetch the projects** from that account.

My requirement is to **display** these **projects in the Drawer NavBar**. (I have a screen that will cater to the navigation, displaying the selected project's details on clicking a project entity in the drawer. Which, again, are fetched through related APIs and so on.) I also want to have my customComponent of logout to empty my state, so that logging in a different account/user does not cause any overlap on the store which is presently happening.

> **Hence, I want a way to connect my Drawer declaration to redux.**

I am using redux-thunk as my middleware and stated below are the relevant code files.

**AppNavigationView.js**

```
let DrawerNavigation = allProjects => {
    return createDrawerNavigator(
        {
            Dashboard: {
                screen: DashboardStack,
                navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
                    return {
                        drawerIcon: () => <Icon name="chart" fontSize={12} />,
                    };
                },
            },
            Workspaces: {
                screen: ProjectNavigator,
                navigationOptions: {
                    // This is the title that displays in the side Drawer
                    title: 'Workspaces',
                    drawerIcon: () => <Icon name="home" fontSize={12} />,
                },
            },
            MyProfile: {
                screen: MyProfileStack,
                navigationOptions: {
                    title: 'Profile',
                    drawerIcon: () => <Icon name="user" fontSize={12} />,
                },
            },
            About: {
                screen: AboutStack,
                navigationOptions: {
                    drawerIcon: () => <Icon name="info" fontSize={12} />,
                },
            },
        },
        {
            // let allProjectObjects = this.allProjects;
            contentComponent: props => (
                <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                    <SafeAreaView forceInset={{ top: 'always', horizontal: 'never' }}>
                        <DrawerItems {...props} />
                        <View
                            style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', paddingLeft: 25 }}
                        >
                            <Icon name="info" fontSize={12} />
                            <TouchableOpacity
                                onPress={() => handleLogoutClick(props)}
                                style={{ paddingLeft: 15 }}
                            >
                                <Text style={{ margin: 16, fontWeight: 'bold', color: 'black' }}>
                                    Logout
                                </Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                        // THIS SAFEAREAVIEW IS COMMENTED OUT, BUT I WANT TO DISPLAY MY 
                        // PROJECTS FROM HERE!!
                        {/* <SafeAreaView>
                            <FlatList
                                data={this.allProjects}
                                renderItem={({ item }) => {
                                    return (
                                        <View
                                            style={{
                                                flexDirection: 'row',
                                                alignItems: 'center',
                                                paddingLeft: 25,
                                            }}
                                        >
                                            <Icon name="home" fontSize={12} />
                                            <TouchableOpacity style={{ paddingLeft: 15 }}>                       
                                                <Text
                                                    style={{
                                                        margin: 12,
                                                        color: 'black',
                                                    }}
                                                >
                                                    {item.name}
                                                </Text>
                                            </TouchableOpacity>
                                        </View>
                                    );
                                }}
                                keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                            />
                        </SafeAreaView> */}
                    </SafeAreaView>
                </View>
            ),
            drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
            drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
            drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle',
        },
    );
};

export const createRootSwitchNavigator = (signedOut = false, allProjectObjects = {}) => {
    return createSwitchNavigator(
        {
            SignedIn: {
                screen: DrawerNavigation(allProjectObjects),
            },
            SignedOut: {
                screen: Login,
            },
        },
        {
            initialRouteName: signedOut ? 'SignedOut' : 'SignedIn',
        },
    );
};
```

**AppScreen.js** (this calls the `Switch Navigator`)

```
    render() {
        if (this.state.isLoading || _.isEmpty(this.props.allProjectObjects)) {
            return <SplashScreen />;
        }

        let Layout = createRootSwitchNavigator(
            this.state.isSignedOut,
            this.props.allProjectObjects,
        );
        let AppContainer = createAppContainer(Layout);
        return <AppContainer />;
    }
```

I have redux connected in this case and fetch projects by dispatching an action.

*But this is only the case wherein the user is already logged in*

In case we take the logging in route and then navigating to the drawerNavigator, I am clueless.

Any help is appreciable. Thanks!